# ssh into intel nuc and run node that require a display

Tags: kinect, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using an intel nuc as the brain for my robot. I want to ssh into the nuc and run nodes that require a display but I want the display to come up on the computer i used t ssh into the nuc

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321009/ssh-into-intel-nuc-and-run-node-that-require-a-display/) by [depps](https://answers.ros.org/users/38293/depps/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-04-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is known as X11 Fowarding and you can setup your ssh to allow X11 forwarding. You will first want to confirm X11 forwarding is enabled on both the client and host computer:

For the client edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
X11Fowarding yes
X11UseLocalhost no
```

For the host edit `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

```
FowardX11 yes
FowardX11Trusted yes
```

After this you can connect from the client to the host with the following ssh flag

```
ssh -X -p SOME_PORT user@server
```

The `-X` flag does the magic here, you can test this by running a sample X application on the host computer such as `xclock` and it should run on your local system

---

Originally posted by [agurman](https://answers.ros.org/users/40767/agurman/) with karma: 111 on 2019-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2